# Infinite scrolling from two different API endpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

*The question could also be titled "attaching two different scroll Event Handlers on `window` and programmatically switching between them*

I have two endpoints, the first one brings me a list of "latest" items:

```
/api/latest.json
```

and the other one is used to perform a search to all items:

```
/api/items.json?q="mission+impossible"
```

Both endpoints accept a "**page_limit**" parameter, as well as a "**page**" parameter, so:

```
/api/latest.json?page_limit=10&page=1
```

will fetch the first page of items, capping to 10 items.

Here is the scenario:

1. As soon as my page loads (assume it's an onLoad/documentLoaded) only the first page of latest items is loaded
2. A scroll event handler is attached to the window which takes care of infinite scrolling

`window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(() => this.handleScroll('api/latest.json'), 450))`

`handleScroll()` takes care of looking when the bottom of the page was reached and if so executes `getItems()` which takes as parameters the url, the page number, and the number of items per page, as well as increases the page_number variable internally.

All this works fine.

Here is where things get tricky:

1. The user performs a search (uses the second endpoint)
2. All results are updated (it's a SPA using Vue.js)
3. The user scrolls down
4. When the bottom of the page is reached, a new request is made BUT
5. it is not the second page of `/api/items.json?page_number=2&q="mission+impossible"` but the one from `/api/latest.json?page_number=2`

So, in theory, the handleScroll function, should be aware (with some Vue.js magic probably) of the current context:

- did the user perform a search or
- is he staring at the initially loaded page of latest.json

Comment: I fail to understand how your `getItems()` function works. Even if it is asynchronous, clearly it either initiates the AJAX request right away or has a magical way of knowing when the `scroll` event has been triggered, since it has already been called and has already returned by then. Or it returns a function that defers the work until `scroll` occurs, but this looks like a convoluted way of doing things. Can you elaborate?

Comment: To put @FrédéricHamidi comment another way: you're assigning the event listener to the *result* of getItems, ie null (most likely).   Did you mean: `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { getItems(...));` ?

Comment: It's not clear how the two endpoints relate and why/when you call one or the other.   A normal infinite scroll would keep the page number in a variable (or hidden input / data attr etc) and call `getItems` as appropriate.   How can you have two different inifinite scrolls?   Or is is that you get latest on load (a by-product of miss-assigning it as per comments above) and only infinite scroll the results?  In which case, simply assign the event listener correctly.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question minimal in order to not discourage answers, but give me 5' and I will elaborate.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi and all : clearer now?

Comment: FYI the question could also be something like "attaching two different scroll Event Handlers on `window` and programmatically switching them"

Comment: @George, your intent is clearer now, yes. Please edit your last comment into your question as to remove all ambiguity, though.

Comment: So, to summarise: page loads, add scroll event listener, page scrolls, event fires.  Why does the event not fire *again* when you scroll *again*?  It doesn't look like you've used a `.one()` equivalent and `.throttle` looks like a debounce rather than a fire-once.   So it should just work as-is...  [is it some quirk of vue?]

Comment: I'm not clear why there needs to be two different handlers... is it not the results only that are scrolling?

Comment: @George, are you perchance trying to merge the two data streams into a single rendering container and want to synchronize that somehow? Otherwise I agree with freedomn -- the two handlers should be able to throttle, request and render independently.

Comment: Because each handler targets a different endpoint, one handler triggers an XHR request from `latest.json` and the other needs to take the `<input>` field's content, append it to the movie search api url, make the different request

Comment: But surely only one of them fires when the user scrolls the page down?  ie there's only one *scroll* handler.

Comment: Or is that you have infinite scroll on latest, *until* the user selects one, then it's on the results?

Comment: @freedomn-m : page loads, event listener added, scroll down, more items fetched. (all good so far.)
Now, user searches for stuff, content is replaced with different items (it's a SPA thing), user scrolls down and *he doesnt get the 2nd page of his search results* , but rather *he gets the 2nd page of "latest.json" which has nothing to do with his search query.. (I think this is the bet I can do to explain it..)

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos ok - I think I'm getting it :)  sorry for being dumb - looked like "latest" was a single result set, based on this statement: "**all** the latest items are loaded".  ie if all the latest items are loaded, you don't need to get any more...

Comment: I re-edited my question and I will re-edit it again to make sure this is clear :)

Comment: Done :) this must be one of the top detailed questions of SO :) Any clues?

Comment: After all that, I'd go with what you suggest at the bottom.  Point the event at a function which checks if the results are shown and call getItems with the relevant url.  Keep paging against each list to keep them separate.  To be more complex: write getItems as a jquery plugin and initiate it twice then enable/disable when results are shown - this would keep the page numbers separate by scope rather than data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you want to have one of two actions fire. The easiest way to accomplish this, would be to write a scroll handler that can decide which action to fire, and then run it accordingly. In the following example I am running them in sequence, but you could decide based on other state if necessary.

For example:

```
 var handlers = [
    getItems('api/latest.json', 10, 1, 450),
    doSearch // handler involving your other endpoint
 ]
 var nextHandler = 0;

 function scrollHandler(e){
   handlers[nextHandler++](e);
   nextHandler = nextHandler % handlers.length; // wrap around if necessary
 }

 window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
```

Comment: I don't get the nextHandler part.. But I see the general picture. You're saying there's an array of methods. But, if one handler is already attached to the window, can you replace him with another one "on-the-fly" ?

Comment: `scrollHandler` is a dispatcher, that figures out which handler to fire based on some criteria (I don't understand your use case fully, so so the above is just an example). `nextHandler` is just an index into the array of handlers so that you know which one to use. The `%` bit just makes sure that when you run off the end (ie nextHandler > 1) that it rolls around to 0 again.

Comment: But my question is, once this `window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)` has been run, can the "things that the `scrollHandler`" do be changed? I thought handlers are registered and only by removing them specifically you chance what they do.. or not?

Comment: `scrollHandler` is a function just like any other function. When the scroll event runs it is effectively running `scrollHander(event)`. So the function can decide what to do every time it is run. You just have to make sure that the information it needs in order to make that decision is in scope.

Comment: So basically: https://jsbin.com/padanomati/edit?js,console,output I just change the flag.

Comment: You could also run `window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)` and add some other listener, but I think it is probably cleaner to do it as I have above.